# How to change Blender's default startup settings?

Tags: customization

How can I change Blender from the default cube/lamp/camera default setup? Also, is it possible to change other features, such as the default view direction (Top, Side, etc) or the Editor type (3D View, Node Editor, Graph Editor, etc)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*File > Defaults > Save Startup File* (also bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> in the 2.7x keymap)  [will save your current settings and setup as the default startup view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/topbar.html#startup-file), meaning it will set everything as the default including the current view(s), whatever data is loaded *(images, models)*, and the *User Interface*. This overrides the startup .blend file found in the config folder and can be used on another machine or similar version of Blender.

[image: screenshot showing the Save Startup File and Load Factory Settings options in File > Defaults]

You can revert back to the factory defaults at any time by using *File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings*.

Comment: see related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences/82#82

Comment: In Blender 2.8, it's: `File -> Defaults -> Save Startup File`, and `File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings`.