# How to change the default value of Image compression?

Tags: export

Hello I found a little problem right now I'm working in a project using blender I bake a lot of textures but since this bakings are a lot of test I want compress at 100% why because I use a Git repository and that increases the repository size.(Of course I try to avoid binary files)

So after explain what I'm doing I'm tired of change the value every time that I open Blender.**Compression value is 15%** I want to change that default when I start blender

[image: ImageCompression]

I already tried to use Ctrl+Alt+U. System Tab->save users settings that is OK with the plugins but I always have to change **Compression value 15%** When I open a new blender file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Blender's default startup settings?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186/how-to-change-blenders-default-startup-settings)

Comment: So the compression value is not part of the User Settings is actually a value of the blend file.

Comment: Correct. The User Preferences doesn't really control default values for values visible in the UI (there would be too many to list in the preferences), that's the job of the startup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the compression level to 100%, then press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>*> Save startup file*.

Note that this will save *everything*, including view position, objects, etc. as default.