# How to add a socket for mapping node?

Tags: node-editor, vector-mapping, texture-coordinates

I use a Mapping Node for modify texture result. But the properties of Mapping Node are fixed. Is possible to add some sockets for Value Node? Then I can change values from somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible without modifying blender's source code. However, in the case of the mapping node, everything it does can be done with regular math nodes.

I've made some nodegroups which re-implement the mapping node accordingly:

[image]

[image]

[Append or link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/81/599) (<kbd>F1</kbd>) the "Scale" "Translate" and "Rotate" nodegroups into your .blend, or put them in your [startup .blend](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/186/599) to keep them at your fingertips at all times ;)

Comment: one more problem... Rotate Group has initial angles....

Comment: @Henry It works for me.. How are you using it? Could you post a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: Deg2Rad Node Group is defined in another .blender file. So node tree is broken. Now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Henry Ah, I forgot to make that group local before uploading.. I've updated the .blend in case anyone else should happen across this.