# Console flashes on launching, then closes (ms-windows)

Tags: windows

I installed blender on a windows 7 64 bit system.  I opened it one time then went to the tutorials.  in the meantime I had a power failure and when I tried to start blender again I get a dos window that closes itself then nothing.

I reinstalled Blender and get the same thing.  I am going to try to uninstall then reinstall but in the mean time, any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE Bill. We can help you but you have to be very specific and include as much information as possible. Does the window print a message? Have you tried installing another version of Blender? It could be a corrupt file etc. Try starting blender from the command line and seeing what it says.

Comment: didnt work for me :( i just start up blender and, it launches a command window ........BANG blender has stopped working.

Comment: Your problem may or may not be a command prompt error. Is there a Windows 7.0/8 command prompt open up when you click on your selected application?

Answer (score 11):

More than likely the problem is that your `startup.blend` and or `userpref.blend` file was corrupted. To fix this, just navigate to the user settings directory and delete them.

On Windows, the directory is located at
`%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender\x.x\config` (where `x.x` is the installed version). See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences/82#82) for more information on how to locate this directory on your os. This can work for both portable copies and installations.

*OR*

When uninstalling the program, tick *Remove all files* (second option) to make it delete the directory and then reinstall.

[image]

The next time you start Blender, it should start normally and if you tweak the interface and or change the user preferences and save them, it will write out new copies of these files with your new settings.

Comment: I ran into this issue, and this worked for me...   I'm going to start making backup copies of these files.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it on my system (Windows 7 32-bit) with a bat file that has the following content:

```
set PYTHONPATH=""
"%ProgramFiles%\Blender Foundation\blender\blender.exe" "%1"
```

Put the above in a file called `blender.bat` and associate `.blend` files with the `blender.bat` file.

Also, make sure that any .blend file pathname has no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say what's going on there Bill, but sounds to me like a registry issue or an over zealous virus scanner that associates the shutdown with the programs running at the time.

**A temporary solution**

It is possible to run blender without installing it, there are portable .zip archives available from either the [main download links](http://www.blender.org/download/get-blender/) on blender.org or daily development builds at [builder.blender.org](http://builder.blender.org/download/)

Unpack any of these zips to a convenient directory, and start blender by clicking the blender.exe from there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a fresh install of windows 7 64bit...

I went to the Blender Foundation folder in program files and ran Blender-app and it worked..

Blender 2.73a