# Blender 2.74 Windows 64bit quits and displays hz issue

Tags: windows, installation

Here is the message that gets displayed:

```
AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 4800hz instead
found bundled python: D:\Blender\2.74\python 
Blender quit
```

I've reinstalled twice and get the same problem. Not sure what I should do to get the program back up and running.

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/console-flashes-on-launching-then-closes-ms-windows

Comment: Al lib: <EE> UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz blender, got 48000hz instead
Kind of annoying, i always get that but blender hardly ever crashes or quits, maybe it is something else. (2.76a-2.78)

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is having issues with the audio configuration.

Go to where Blender is installed in the Windows Explorer. The Default Installation Path is C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender.

When inside the Blender Folder, hold down the *Shift key*, and *right-click* any folder inside the **Blender Folder** (the 2.74 folder will work just fine), then choose the option "*Open Command Window here*").

With the new **command window** open, you should have a prompt that looks like this:

*C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender>* or one reflecting the path to the Blender folder.

From that prompt, type:

`blender.exe -noaudio` (make sure there is a *space* between the "exe" and the "-". Blender should start like normal.

You can also set it to use a specific sound system:

`blender.exe -setaudio SDL`

Other options include, NULL, OPENAL, and JACK.

If it still crashes, start Blender with the debug flag to show any other errors or issues leading up to this error.

`blender.exe -d`

Comment: Tried that once I found where the program was actually installed (not in my C drive) and what I got was the same message as before minus the Blender quit part and the following was added to it: D:\Blender\2.74\python unknown argument, loading as file: --noaudio. Error: Cannot read file C:\Users\Kerabe\--noaudio': No such file or directory

Comment: How can I do that before getting Blender loaded? Unfortunatley I'm a computer "user" and not too well schooled in how to trouble shoot them.

Comment: It keeps wanting to look in the Users file and there is nothing in there for 2.74

Comment: Blender is not loaded into the default location as C drive is used exclusively for the OS. It is in the D drive in a file named Blender so I think that this may be a little harder to figure out for me than I had hoped.

Comment: Oh just a sec, I had to reread what you wrote before it clicked in . I'll try it right now.

Comment: So far I've been trying all the variations you have given me and this is basically what kind of error I'm getting: D:\Blender>blender.exe --setaudio SDL AL lib: (EE) UpdateDeviceParams: Failed to set 44100hz, got 48000hz instead found bundled python: D:Blender\2.74\python unknown argument, loading as file: --setaudio Error: Cannot read file 'D:\Blender\--setaudio' : No such file or directory Error: Cannot read file 'D:\Blender\SDL': No such file or directory    So that is what I get for the other variations too :(

Comment: Tried it with just one dash and did not get an error in the command box but the program will still not open. Just a blank window.

Comment: 2.62 and 2.69 are the only ones in users. I don't know why 2.74 is not there. I downloaded the blender/python bundle (blender-2.74-windows64) from the Blender.org site and that is what I installed just changing the location to my D drive vise the default C drive. I'm using a SSHD for my C drive and it is only around 250 gigs so I keep everything off of it that I can.

Comment: There is the 2.74 file in my D:\Blender file along with versions going back to 2.58.

Comment: Would it also be safe to copy the 2.74 in to the users location instead of the contents of the 2.69? I have had this program up and running and all these problems only started a couple of days ago so I would think that there should be valid info in the 2.74 file.

Comment: Naw, I just tried copying the 2.74 into the users location and it didn't' work and I tried replacing the 2.74 info with the 2.69 and the program still didn't work. This is a real tough one.

Comment: It's back to the original error. Well I have to go now as it is after 23:30 here and my 3 year old just woke up crying. I will try again tomorrow and I would also like to thank you very much for trying to help me with this! Take care and good night :)

Comment: Any time at all. I apologize that I couldn't help find a solution.

Comment: All right then...this morning I tried again with the "-d" and it did not work so I uninstalled yet again and this time I scrubbed everything out of the computer that had anything to do with Blender. I then went back to Blender.org and downloaded the program and put it in a completely different hard drive and then installed. It put nothing in the C drive under my roaming profile at all. I got the exact same error message as I did from the beginning so I am completely stumped with this problem.

Comment: So maybe it could be my system. Here is what makes up my system: AMD FX-8370E Eight-Core Processor 3.31 GHz; 32.0 GB RAM; 64 bit operating system; Windows 7 Pro (service pack 1) all built on a Sabertooth 990FX R2.0 motherboard and I have a Sapphire AMD FirePro W7100 (FireGL V) professional Graphics card. Maybe this will help figure out what could be wrong.

Comment: Try to keep comments to a minimum for future clarity. If you need, you can always move these to a chatroom.

Comment: iKlsR, I just read up on chat and if I understand it correctly, I would need a rep of 20 to open up a chat about this subject. Could this subject be moved by DBrown, the person who has been helping me with this issue?

Comment: Hey @KeithBell luckily I was passing back and saw this, put an @ before my name or I won't see it. I created a chatroom [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24630/room-for-dbrown-and-keithbell), you should see the invites in your notifications. Will purge the comments later.