# Blender crashes when opened

Tags: windows, installation

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of blender for the first time but every time I run the blender.exe file a window with text similar to cmd opens for a split second and closes. I was able to get a screen shot and here is what comes 
[image: system console with error]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32003/blender-2-74-windows-64bit-quits-and-displays-hz-issue

Answer (score 1):

First of all try running Blender as Administrator.
If that does not work try those steps suggested in [developer.Blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/T44416):

> - Ensure your GPU driver supports at least OpenGL 1.4
> - Ensure you have installed MSVC2013 redistributable [package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784)
> - Try  to disable any running antivirus
> - Ensure you have no python executable available in your %path% environment variables
> - Try to start Blender in factory settings       (--factory-startup commandline option - this will show whether this  is a userpref or
>     add-on issue or not).
> - Try to place this [dll](http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/win64/opengl32.dll) next to     your blender.exe (software OGL, will be slow, but will show whether  this is a driver issue or
>     not).