# Blender closes when opened (flashes command window)

Tags: windows, installation

When I try to load Blender, it flashes a command window and gives a failure (very similar to the one described in the link below).  It then opens Blender (a gray screen) and closes it.

[More information](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32003/blender-2-74-windows-64bit-quits-and-displays-hz-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1)

When I follow the instructions provided in the linked thread, it gives me an error message (shown below).

[image]

Please help, as I am trying to finish a development project and this is stopping me from doing so!

Comment: For powershell you need to run ./blender.exe -noaudio to get a useful error message. Currently it is just saying it can't find the blender executable.

Comment: I added that and it's giving this new error message:

Found bundled python.

Then it says 'ERROR: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.  When I go where it says (blender/2.79/python), there are two folders: bin and lib.