# I have no icon to click on to open blender just the install wizard under downloads

Tags: installation

I only have the install wizard after finishing install. There is nothing to click on to open blender. I have installed 64 and 32.

Comment: What OS? Does Blender folder with executable presents at path selected in install wizrd?

Comment: I am running windows 8.

Comment: I get a black screen with a flashing cursor but it disappears quickly.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/console-flashes-on-launching-then-closes-ms-windows

Comment: Uninstall blender. Delete the C:\Programs Files\Blender Foundation folder, delete any preference files on C:\Users\your user\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation. Now Reinstall **only** the version that matches your OS, not both.