# The blender won't start up

Tags: installation

I'm completly new with all of this. 
I've downloaded blender from official website, but it doesn't work.

When I try to opend blender.exe it shows console for quarter of a second and closes with no notification from windows.

I menaged to catch console on screenshot, here it is.
[image]

I tried to reinstall it three times, but, sadly, nothing works

It's windows 7 64

I hope I can get some help, that would be great :)

(I'm not too good witch computer nor English, so don't get too complicated with wording please?...)

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/console-flashes-on-launching-then-closes-ms-windows

Comment: you probably need to update your pc via **windows update**. https://developer.blender.org/T44238

Answer (score -1):

My instance of Blender mysteriously stopped working on Win 10 64-bit.  The Visual Studio debugger said, "unhandled exception 0xc0000904."

I uninstalled Blender 2.75, re-installed the MS Visual Studio redistributable (msvcr120.dll), installed Blender 2.77, went through the usual windows service troubleshooting steps starting from a clean boot.  All no help.

I finally ran the Program Compatibility troubleshooter, the diagnostics log in %appdata%/temp said "python incompatible".

So I deleted the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Voila! Now Blender starts fine.

Comment: if you post the exact same answer over and over in multiple questions it will look like an automated spam answer, at least word your posts differently

Comment: You don't read carefully.  The answer was not exactly the same, it was edited and corrected.  Do you want correct information?  Or strict adherence to some unpublished style guide?  I don't give a rats ass about your social scoring system, I'm trying to give correct solutions to issues I bring up.