# How do you keep blender from shutting down?

Tags: windows

Every time i go to render something completely, stops and shuts down destroying everything i have worked on. what am i doing wrong that keeps me from working?

- right now i am using windows 7 (Yes i had to down grade because of an issue).
- Packard Bell laptop with sufficient space on hard drive. 
  I tunes is present on the computers, i heard some where that these two programs do not get along with each other.

Comment: Does it really destroy what you have done, even if the file has been saved? If so, look for a file with a name like yourfile.blend1. Blender uses .blend1 extensions when it crashes..... Without more info, that is the only thing I can think of to suggest, but details welcome...

Comment: And possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/console-flashes-on-launching-then-closes-ms-windows

Comment: Have you updated to the latest release?  Bugs are being fixed all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If Blender crashes, it's a bug in Blender (or you're doing *really* crazy things, but let's not assume that). Please help us Blender developers to fix this bug.

1. Investigate how you can make Blender crash as fast as possible, and as reliably as possible.
2. Think of a way to describe the bug you just found.
3. [Search for the bug](https://developer.blender.org/search/query/advanced/), to see if someone else already reported it.
4. If it hasn't been reported yet, [report your bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/). Be sure to include an example blend file and the steps required for the developer to make Blender crash.

Especially this last step is important. If the developers can reliably make Blender crash the way you made it crash, it will help tremendously in getting things fixed.

Comment: But most importantly. Use the **Save** function, Setup **Auto-Save** and you won't loose anything....