# Removal of Program to reinstall not gone entirely

Tags: add-on, installation

I have 2.79 and a heap of addons that do not work when they should be, Hard Ops, etc.  Also, my Alt Click on edge loops stopped working so I figured I should reinstall Blender.  All the new versions say Install 2.8 but I can't seem to install it, also, I have tried to remove 2.79 to do a new clean install, I watch Windows remove the program, then I go and remove the folders, reinstall Blender, and it is the same version I tried to remove, complete with Addons, and all.

How do I completely remove everything to do a clean install since I am clearly not doing that very well, and

How do I "Install" 2.8 when I only get an exe to start the program.  There doesn't seem to be any sort of "install" to place Hard Ops, Box Cutter, etc. in a directory for 2.8.

My apologies if these are repeated questions, I could not find anything related to them, and thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Console flashes on launching, then closes (ms-windows)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/console-flashes-on-launching-then-closes-ms-windows)

Comment: The great thing about Blender is you do not need to install it. Go to the download page and select the stand alone version .ZIP. You can then unzip it and run it from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

To remove blender completely go to **Control Panel** -> **Remove a program** -> remove blender, then go to **`C:\Users\Your-Username\AppData\Roaming\`** and remove the folder called **Blender Foundation** (This is where blender saves it's stuff), then reinstall blender.

about Blender 2.8, here is the link to download it: https://builder.blender.org/download/

just download the .zip folder, unzip it, then run the Blender.exe file (You don't need/have to "Install" it), Thats it :)