# Blender icons have no label

Tags: interface

I have Blender downloaded and installed on my computer. On startup it shows icons having no labels. As a newbie it is virtually impossible to follow any tutorial with this interface. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Blender loads scripts at startup. It seems it cannot find these. The *most likely* reason is that the path to it has some characters Blender can't read or a file is corrupt. Here is what you can try.

1. Reinstall and clear all user settings.

   On Windows, the directory is located at  `C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.6x`. Delete this folder and reinstall Blender. See [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences/82#82) for more information on how to locate this directory. This can work for both portable copies and installations.

   *OR*

   When uninstalling the program, tick *Remove all files* (second option) to make it delete the directory and then reinstall.

   [image]
2. Try a [portable version](http://builder.blender.org/download/).
   *Still clear the old folder from the first point.* Since portable builds use the files they ship with, it should work with the files it comes with or generate new ones as needed.