# Shared preferences/addons across different machines (e.g. Dropbox)

Tags: workflow, customization

how do you guys keep your settings when switching computers (e.g. home/work)?

I'm still in the process of finding my perfect setup, and I would like to have all the changes that I make and all the addons I install available on all machines that I work on.

Do you just link your 2.75 folder to a dropbox folder to keep everything synced? That would even sync unwanted stuff like recent projects and bookmarks. And the filepaths are stored there as well which are not the same on every machine/OS.

Comment: cg cookie had an article on this back in 2013, only way I could get to it was through google's cached pages. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y1HkXb3UxOgJ:https://cgcookiearchive.com/blender/2013/01/31/sync-blender-config-dropbox/+&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences) should help. Copying startup.blend (this contains your startup scene) and userpref.blend (this contains your user preferences) to Dropbox and syncing them should have the result you're after. You would have to manually copy and paste the files to and from the Dropbox folder on each machine each time you changed them, however, so it won't be an automatic update.

ex. Working at home, make changes to User Preferences, copy userpref.blend to Dropbox, go to work, move userpref.blend from Dropbox to Blender folder. You would also have to do the same with the addons you installed.

Comment: please add a bit more to this answer. As it is, it is a  little more then a  link only answer (even if it is an internal link).

Comment: Thanks, I figured so much, but it is really not satisfying. Anyway since Tons 2.8 announcement yesterday I have some hopes that this will be improved. If no one comes up with something better I will accept your answer later today.

Comment: as mentionned in CGCookie's solution, use drobpox and symbolic links

Comment: @oenvoyage Well, I never heard of symbolic links under windows, so it won't work on every machine...

Comment: @BojidarMarinov symbolic links work without installing anything under Vista and up. the syntax is `mklnk /d "DESIRED_LOCATION" "CURRENT_LOCATION"` , read up on mklink

Answer (score 0):

I store my scripts in a folder that is in my SVN repository. (i.e. .\projects\art_settings\Blender\2.7x\config) since I frequently add/modify my own Python scripts in there.

Every new release of Blender, I go into User Preferences > File > Scripts and point it to that directory.

As far as the config file are concerned though, that other link from the previous answer probably would be the best solution.