# Centralized Addon Library

Tags: add-on

I teach high school students using Blender and was wondering if there is a way to point Blender on client computers to look at a centralized addon library on the local network.

Comment: Possible similar solution from this post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34137/shared-preferences-addons-across-different-machines-e-g-dropbox

Comment: The [blender sync](https://cloud.blender.org/blog/introducing-blender-sync) feature of the blender cloud add-on could be useful maybe. While subscription to the cloud is not free, the add-on and using the sync feature is.