# how to import previous settings in 2.76b?

Tags: customization

I installed it on ubuntu, just direct extract from gz2 package.
[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences) described a way to import previous setting. However, there is no such option at 1st time I start the new version

```
>>> bpy.utils.user_resource("CONFIG")
'/home/user/.config/blender/2.76/config/'

ls /home/user/.config/blender/2.76
ls: cannot access /home/user/.config/blender/2.76: No such file or directory
```

We can see there is no config file at all. Still there is no such option on splash screen.

I also tried:

```
>>> bpy.ops.wm.copy_prev_settings()
Error: Source path '/home/user/.config/blender/2.75' exists
```

However, this is not true. The only folder exist in that /home/user/.config/blender is 2.71
There must be some bugs?

Comment: How did you install blender? What operating system are you on?

Comment: @gandalf3 I updated the post

Comment: Curious.. I'm on archlinux, and everything works as expected (also installing from the blender.org archive). Is there anything in any of the [other configuration locations](http://blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing_blender/directorylayout.html)? (not sure why there would be.. But I can't think of anything else atm)

Comment: @gandalf3 I get it. It seems like in WM_OT_copy_prev_settings, it will automatically check if ver_old exists. It actually have a wrong error message. The message should be 2.75 does not exist. Does that means it can only import from 2.75?

Comment: That appears to be it. You should be able to simply copy/move the configuration directory from whatever the last version you had to `~/.config/blender/2.76`. AFAIK that's all `copy_prev_settings()` does to begin with.

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks! I think we should improve this function to convert invalid settings. So far I found several config items were wrong. For example some addons changed their names. Maybe some variables also changed their names.

Comment: Huh.. That's very bizarre. Can you tell which addons these were? In the meantime I've [reported the misleading error message](https://developer.blender.org/T46699).

Comment: @gandalf3 It is not bizarrre. Those addons have been updated and reorganized in newer version. addons in 2.7.1:
    ['io_import_scene_dxf', 'node_efficiency_tools'] 
addons in 2.7.6:
    ['io_import_dxf',  'node_wrangler']
i think in each version, we should create a change list, then let the import function try to automatically migrate those options.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought addons you had installed were magically renaming themselves or something :P That sounds nice, but then someone has to maintain the changelist..