# How do I export user preferences from blender 2.77 to 2.78?

Tags: export, customization, theme

When I upgraded to blender 2.78, I couldn't recover my old user preferences settings. I had my own theme, my own hotkeys, and my preferred addons. I
 tried to figure out which files but I couldn't .
Note: I downloaded blender 2.78 as zip file not installer
[image]

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences

Comment: Also - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23338/where-is-the-startup-file-stored

Comment: [This explains](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html) the locations of data files, you can manually find the previous config and copy it to the new version.