# Transfering add-ons between blender builds

Tags: add-on, versions

So, I got the blender 2.83 alpha build and, I have all of my bizillion add-ons on 2.82 beta. If I download a new version of 2.82, it will automatically update the newest version of 2.82 with all of my add-ons. But, if I download 2.83, since it's a different build, it will start from scratch. So basically my question is, **Is there a way to transfer all of my add-ons/settings from my 2.82b build to my 2.83a build?**

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get a new version of Blender you will see this welcome screen:

[image]

Here in bottom of this window you will see something like "Load 2.xx Settings". If you press on it, your settings, add-ons and configs will be properly copied.

## What if don't you see this button on the welcome screen (pressed save settings before)?

Navigate to folder:

Linux

```
~/.config/blender
```

Mac

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Blender/
```

Windows

```
%APPDATA%(Program files)\Blender Foundation\Blender
```

And remove folder with name equal newest version number. That makes blender launches "like first time", and you will get  "Load 2.xx Settings" button.