# cant access my user preferences in 2.82

Tags: customization

I just downloaded Blender 2.82 (because Ctrl Z kept crashing the program on 2.81) and I cant figure out how to access my old user preferences which took me hours to set up. I copied startup.blend and userpref.blend into the same subdirectory as the .exe file  and into the config subdirectory under user/appdata/roaming/app data/Blender Foundation/blender 2.82/config but it still doesn't open with my old settings. What shall I do?

Comment: Hello :). This thread should hep: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/78. There are some differences when using ZIP vs installer. In the worst case reinstall 2.82 and click *Copy Previous Settings*.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166953/is-losing-my-settings-upon-updating-a-problem-with-the-steam-version-of-blender

Comment: I tried reinstalling but saw no place on the splash screen to Copy Previous Settings.