# Do I have to re-download my add-ons after Steam automatically updated Blender?

Tags: add-on

I can't seem to find an answer anywhere online so I thought id ask, I'm still fairly new to blender. But in 2.82 I had things like the hardops add-on, UVpackmaster etc., but when steam automatically updated Blender to v2.83 I lost all my add-ons I had. Is there a way to get them back? or do I have to go re-download all of them?

Comment: Related and possibly a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/166953/is-losing-my-settings-upon-updating-a-problem-with-the-steam-version-of-blender

Comment: When Blender starts-up first time, there is an option to copy the settings from the previous version. If you click on it, the add-ons will be copied to the newer version.

Comment: That much I did find out, however I didn't know this when I started up the new build and clicked new settings. Is there a way to go back?