# Is the adjustable settings when you first load in an object bugged?

Tags: modeling

When you first load in an object in Blender you usually get a pop up in the bottle left corner with options like minor radius and stuff like that to adjust. That pops up but its blacked out and I can not edit anything. I need to use this for a model I am working on. Can someone please help?[image: It's greyed out and I can't select anything]

Comment: Hello :). This seems to be some kind of a random bug mentioned [here on bugtracker](https://developer.blender.org/T60770). Some mentioned solutions - restarting Blender, using a different version, deleting the preferences file...

Comment: How do I remove my preferences file?

Comment: This could help: [How would I import/export Blender's preferences?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/78/78972)