# How to update my blender without losing all my settings on mac

Tags: osx, versions

How do i update to blender 2.91 on Mac
i currently have version 2.83. How do I update to version 2.91 useing Homebrew?
without overwriting

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the startup.blend and the userpref.blend to a different folder, update blender,  and copy the preferences back to the original folder. See [How would I import/export Blender's preferences?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78/how-would-i-import-export-blenders-preferences)